# How can I change option styles when get the options dynamically in ChoiceGroup?

Tags: reactjs, office-ui-fabric

I am trying to create choice group with dynamic options. also I need to change the styles of each option. I tried it using classname but it was not success.Can some one help for this?

```
let numbers = [];
for(let i=0;i<10;i++){
    numbers.push({
        key:i,text:i,checked: false
    });
}

<ChoiceGroup className="numbers" key="numbers" options={numbers} onChanged={this.onRecentMatterChanged}/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following example demonstrates how to generate `options` data for `ChoiceGroup` component and customize options styling via `ChoiceGroup.styles` prop:

```
const generateOptions = (count: number): IChoiceGroupOption[] => {
  return Array.from(Array(count), (_, i) => {
    return {
      key: i.toString(),
      text: `Option ${i}`,
      checked: false
    };
  });
};

export default class ChoiceGroupBasicExample extends React.Component<{}, {}> {
  private options: any[];
  constructor(props: {}) {
    super(props);
    this.options = generateOptions(10);
  }

  public render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ChoiceGroup
          className="defaultChoiceGroup"
          defaultSelectedKey="4"
          options={this.options}
          label="Pick one"
          required={true}
          styles={{
            flexContainer: [
              {
                backgroundColor: "#ADD8E6",
                selectors: {
                  ".ms-ChoiceField": {
                    color: "#00008B",
                    fontWeight: 600
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Details:

- `flexContainer` - the name of container for options
- `ms-ChoiceField` - *default* class name for option container, via `selectors` property we override styles

[Here is a demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-qyujxx) for your reference

Follow [Component Styling](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-react/wiki/Component-Styling) for a comprehensive guide on how to style components in Fabric